# Grouped bar charts each group different level in chart.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, bar-chart, chart.js

using char. JS bar chart, First group Car  data (fuel,EMI,service), each group having individual label how to split group individual label

```
let randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*5000)};
    return {
      labels: ["car","Recharge","Food","May","June","July"],
      datasets : [
            {
                fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.8)',
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()],
        labels: ["fuel","Emi","service"],
            },
      {
                fillColor : [chartColors.white, chartColors.gossip, chartColors.blueStone, chartColors.surfieGreen, chartColors.silverTree, chartColors.gossip ],
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()],
        labels: ["DTH","postpaid","prepaid"],
            },
            {
                fillColor : [chartColors.white, chartColors.gossip, chartColors.blueStone, chartColors.surfieGreen, chartColors.silverTree, chartColors.gossip ],
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()],label: 'sadf'
            }

        ]         
    }
```

her ref image  [image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not seeing the tooltip label is because you used the incorrect label config option.  The option is called `label` not `labels` and only accepts a single string (not an array of strings).  If you pass in an array of strings to `label` then chart.js simply assembles a comma separated string for each index in the array for the label.

With that said, I can see what you are attempting to do, but unfortunately, there is no way to do this using Chart.js.  A dataset always represents a data value per each category label.  In other words, each index in a dataset's `data` array maps to the same index in the `labels` array (which is defined outside of the dataset).

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/ZeOXxX) to show what I mean.

As you can see, each dataset spans across all categories (labels).  You cannot have 3 datasets for 'car', 3 datasets for 'Recharge', etc.  The best you could hope to do is set a value of 0 for the categories that the dataset does not belong to, but it makes the graph appear quite confusing.

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/pebdzp) showing that.